# oracle - data aggregation with 15 min interval for 1 hour data from start time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to get data from Oracle Table in which I have one datefield called `periodstarttime` and I want to get only the data aggregated(aggregation must be done for 1hr data) at minutes 00th,15th,30th,45th in a day with input data in 5 minute intervals

For example, if in my table I have periodstarttime as

```
periodstarttime        data
05/04/2017 1:00:00      10
05/04/2017 1:05:00       1
05/04/2017 1:10:00       2
05/04/2017 1:15:00       3
05/04/2017 1:20:00       4
05/04/2017 1:25:00       5
05/04/2017 1:30:00 
and so on....
```

then I want my result to look like:

```
periodstarttime         data with 1hr aggregation
05/04/2017 1:00:00      data with 1hr aggregation from 1.00 to 2.00
05/04/2017 1:15:00      data with 1hr aggregation from 1.15 to 2.15
05/04/2017 1:30:00      data with 1hr aggregation from 1.30 to 2.30
05/04/2017 1:45:00      data with 1hr aggregation from 1.45 to 2.45
```

Comment: Create an example so you can give expected output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TRUNC()` and `CASE` to truncate to the nearest 15 minute interval and then use an analytic function with a windowing clause to get the sum over a rolling window:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       periodstarttime,
       SUM( data ) OVER ( ORDER BY periodstarttime
                          RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '0' MINUTE PRECEDING
                                AND     INTERVAL '45' MINUTE FOLLOWING
                        )
         AS hour_total,
       'data with 1hr aggregation from '
         || TO_CHAR( periodstarttime, 'HH24:MI' )
         || ' to '
         || TO_CHAR( periodstarttime + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'HH24:MI' )
         AS range
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN periodstarttime < TRUNC( periodstarttime, 'HH24' ) + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
           THEN TRUNC( periodstarttime, 'HH24' )
           WHEN periodstarttime < TRUNC( periodstarttime, 'HH24' ) + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
           THEN TRUNC( periodstarttime, 'HH24' ) + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
           WHEN periodstarttime < TRUNC( periodstarttime, 'HH24' ) + INTERVAL '45' MINUTE
           THEN TRUNC( periodstarttime, 'HH24' ) + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
           ELSE TRUNC( periodstarttime, 'HH24' ) + INTERVAL '45' MINUTE
         END AS periodstarttime,
         data
  FROM   table_name
)
ORDER BY periodstarttime;
```

Comment: but the resulting table contains same periodstarttime twice or more( 00 for 00,05,10) when periodstarttime falls between 00 and 15,but i need aggregation exactly for minute values 00,15,30,45 which also includes 05,10,20,25...for example in a day,i need only 96 samples (periodstarttime as 00,15,30,45)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Windowing_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF51202) of Analytic Functions.

Would be like this

```
select periodstarttime, 
   SUM(DATA) OVER (RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING ORDER BY periodstarttime),
   'data with 1hr aggregation from '||FIRST_VALUE(periodstarttime) OVER (RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING ORDER BY periodstarttime)
     ||' to '||LAST_VALUE(periodstarttime) OVER (RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING ORDER BY periodstarttime)
FROM ...
WHERE EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM periodstarttime) IN (0,15,30,45)
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with this: there is no aggregation into 15 minute periods (i.e. if the `11:00` entry is missing then `11:05` and `11:10` will also be ignored); the analytic function needs an `ORDER BY` clause or you get `ORA-30485`; and, if the `periodstarttime` is a date column then using `MINUTE` as the field to `EXTRACT` is invalid (it needs to be a `TIMESTAMP`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 01:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 10 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 01:05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 20 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 01:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 30 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 01:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 40 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 01:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 50 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 01:25:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 60 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 01:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 70 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 01:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 80 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 01:50:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 90 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 02:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 100 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 02:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 110 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 02:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 120 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 02:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 130 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 02:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 140 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/04/2017 03:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') periodstarttime, 150 DATA FROM dual)
-- End of setting up data in your_table; you would not need the above since you already have a table with data in it
-- See the below SQL for the main statement:
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(periodstarttime, 'hh') + FLOOR((TRUNC(periodstarttime, 'mi') - TRUNC(periodstarttime, 'hh'))/(15/1440))*15/1440 periodstarttime,
       sum(DATA) OVER (ORDER BY TRUNC(periodstarttime, 'hh') + FLOOR((TRUNC(periodstarttime, 'mi') - TRUNC(periodstarttime, 'hh'))/(15/1440))*15/1440
                       RANGE BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 60/1440 FOLLOWING) sum_over_next_hour
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY periodstarttime;

PERIODSTARTTIME  SUM_OVER_NEXT_HOUR
---------------- ------------------
05/04/2017 01:00                660
05/04/2017 01:15                850
05/04/2017 01:30                770
05/04/2017 01:45                690
05/04/2017 02:00                750
05/04/2017 02:15                540
05/04/2017 02:30                290
05/04/2017 03:00                150
```

This works by:

1. finding the period start times, which we do by finding the minutes of each periodstarttime, dividing it by 15 minutes, finding the floor of that and then multiplying that new number by 15 minutes. That separates the times into 15 minute groups.
2. Now we know the groups, we can do a cumulative sum. Because we want values across the hour, we need to do a range between the current period and the current period + 1 hour. N.B. This is inclusive, so that the 02:00 values will be included in the cumulative sum for the 01:00 period. If you don't want that, change the range so that it goes up to 59 minutes (which is fine, since our periods are now 0, 15, 30 or 45 minutes past the hour).